# Issue with Fancybox version: 2.0.4

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox, onload, fancybox-2

I know lots of people have asked this question before, I have tried all the mentioned solutions but doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Basically i am trying to set the height and width of fancy-box iframe based up on the size of the image which is in that iframe. Please have a look at the attached image. I have used the following code, also i have tried `parent.$.fancybox.update();` in the page where the image is.

```
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    autoSize: 'false',
    fitToView: 'false',
    afterLoad: function() {
      resizeTimer = setInterval(function () {
        var ht = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('img.tag_image').height();
        if(ht != null)
        {
          this.height = ht;
          clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        }
      },100)
    }
});
```

[image: fancybox with image in it]

[image: Another fancybox]

Comment: any particular reason why the image has to be in an `iframe`? Could you also show the html you are using to fire fancybox?

Comment: I have another fancy-box inside, So i have to use the iframe then another fancybox to perform some operations over image.I have added `class="iframe"` to a link.

Comment: So what you want is to have two fancybox opened at the same time? if so, resizing the first fancybox to fit the image size won't help

Comment: I have just updated the question with another image. Please have a look.

Comment: I want to have first fancybox resized on load as per size of image and the second fancybox will only open on image click.

Comment: If you resize the first fancybox as per size of image, your second fancybox won't fit in the iframe

Comment: In this particular case the image is small but in most cases image will be bigger and the second iframe will fit( for small images i can add some value to height to make it bigger)

Comment: Could you show your html?

Comment: `<%= link_to "AddInfo", new_image_tag_path(image.id), :class => "iframe" %>` this basically generates a link with a class as "iframe" and goes to an action that has image tag `image_tag(@image, :huge, { :class => "tag_image" })` Following MVC (Rails)